# Facebook Javascript SDK inside a Spotify App, possible?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, spotify

I guess the title is clear enough.
I would like to import the Javascript SDK of Facebook inside a Spotify App. Mainly to use the Dialog feature.

Does someone know if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

possible answer/workaround. https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/09321954e7.html

the API has a showAuthenticationDialog, but what it actually does is that it shows a popup that closes when the url parameter is loaded inside that popup. if the authenticatewith facebook isn't enough for you then this might be a possible solution to use, you can use it with facebooks page too. if you just open a link regularly it will open up outside Spotify.

you still might be able to use the facebook js sdk though, but if it uses popups you'll need to use this in it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the JS SDK to use the Dialog feature. All dialogs have a plain old URL you can send users to (within a popup, or the main window).

For example, the Feed dialog:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
```

Comment: This link redirects me to the browser to display the Dialog, I want to have the Dialog directly inside my Spotify App, like the method auth.authenticateWithFacebook does.

Comment: Are you able to use iframes, lightboxes, etc. within Spotify apps?